# Error when starting vm on the qemu/kvm network: Failed to write pid file

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, libvirt, qemu

Libvirt has stopped working altogether on any VM (windows or linux) on the `qemu/kvm` networt and has the following error each time I try to start something:

```
error: internal error: Failed to start QEMU binary /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 for probing: qemu-system-x86_64: cannot create PID file: Failed to write pid file
```

If I try to create a new VM on the `qemu/kvm` network, I'm given:

```
Host does not support any virtualization options
```

However, running and starting VM's on a `qemu/kvm user session` network works fine. I have also been able to use the `qemu/kvm` network before without problems for a long time, and I'm unsure what's triggered it to stop working now.

I have tried starting the `qemu-system-x86_64` binary from a terminal and that works fine too.

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was solved by a helpful someone on the libvirt mailing list. My `/var` partition was out of space, and that's why libvirt couldn't create any `PID` file.

Comment: Just had the same problem. Thanks for posting this answer!